# Usage of the Active Report In the Delphi6

Tags: delphi, activereports

Can I use the Active Report with the Delphi6?

Comment: How do I use the 'x' in 'y', is not a real question IMO.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveReports COM is not supported in Delphi 6. However, you could create a COM DLL exposing functions to render your reports and use that VB DLL from a delphi app. As I recall, there were some solid reports writers available for Delphi 6 such as "Report Builder", "Duck Report", Rave, quick reports. Not sure if they are all still active or not though.